# Beamer, TiKZ, and commutative diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, memoir

I have a commutative diagram that renders without issue in a memoir document, but, when I copy the code into a beamer slide, the mapping text becomes super imposed over the arrows.

Is there a solution to this? A few Google searches find nothing.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: If you are scaling the picture add the `transform scale` option to the TikZ picture.